# activeClassName is not working for Link in component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I am trying to use the activeClassName however somehow its not working. My Links are in separate Header component. Following is code details.

client.js

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import  {Router, Route, IndexRoute, hashHistory} from "react-router";

import  Layout from "./components/Layout";
import  Archive from "./pages/Archive";
import  Feature from "./pages/Feature";
import  Profile from "./pages/Profile";
import  Settings from "./pages/Settings";

const app = document.getElementById('app');
ReactDOM.render(
 <Router history={hashHistory}>
   <Route path="/" component={Layout}>
     <IndexRoute component={Feature}></IndexRoute>
     <Route path="archive(/:articleid)" component={Archive}></Route>
     <Route path="profile" component={Profile}></Route>
     <Route path="settings" component={Settings}></Route>
     <Route path="feature" component={Feature}></Route>
   </Route>
 </Router>,
  app

);
```

Layout.js

```
import React from "react";
import  Header from "./Header";
import Footer from "./Footer";
export  default class Layout extends React.Component {
  navigate () {
    console.log(this.props);
    this.props.history.replaceState(null,"/settings");
  }
  render () {
    return (
     <div>
       <Header navigate={this.navigate.bind(this)} title="Welcome to React based Application :-)"></Header>
       {this.props.children}

     </div>
    )
  }
}
```

Header.js

```
import React from "react";

import Title from "./Header/Title";
import  {Link} from "react-router";

export  default class Header extends React.Component {

  render () {

    return (
      <div>
        <Title title={this.props.title}></Title>
        <span><Link to="archive" className="btn btn-success" activeClassName="btn-primary"> archive</Link> &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</span>
        <span><Link to="profile" className="btn btn-success">profile</Link>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</span>
        <span><Link to="settings" className="btn btn-success">settings</Link>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</span>
        <span><Link to="feature" className="btn btn-success">feature</Link>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</span>

      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

Please help.

Comment: What version of react-router are you using?

Comment: I am using    "react-router": "^2.0.1", "history": "^2.0.1", "react": "^0.14.6", "react-dom": "^0.14.6".

Comment: I updated my libraries yesterday and I started having this issue.

In my case the issue was related to "react-redux" lib.